# Why do I not see "Delete App" in Test Flight for my app

Tags: app-store-connect, testflight

Why cannot I delete my app from Test Flight?

I am the Team Agent.
The App is in "Prepare For Submission".
I do not have any Builds (I deleted them).
I do not have any connections to Game Center or anything else that I need to remove in order to be able to delete the app (as best as I can tell).
The app has never been to the App Store.

Comment: You cannot delete the app until you once have the app on sale.

Comment: But these apps never are going to the app store. There is no way to delete them then?